# Cycle through Divs toggle class on each one

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi all I need to cycle through 4 divs and toggle their class. I need one to complete the toggle class function then move to the next and toggle class then the next and so on. After the fourth has toggled it's class, the cycle needs to start back at the first and cycle through again continuously. Here's my broken code thus far:

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (i < 5) {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#screen_' + i).toggleClass('over-to-charts-screen');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#screen_' + i).toggleClass('over-to-charts-screen');
      }, 1000);
    }, 5000)
    i++;
    cycle();
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.over-to-charts-screen {
  padding-top: 38%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  background-color: #ec1d0c;
  background-color: rgba(255, 48, 0, .7);
  transition: background-color .7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="pop-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_1">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_1" id="screen_1">
      <h5>Pop<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="rock-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_2">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_2" id="screen_2">
      <h5>Rock<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="country-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_3">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_3" id="screen_3">
      <h5>Country<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="latin-charts">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_4">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_4" id="screen_4">
      <h5>Latin<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Just to clarify - which class needs to be toggled?

Comment: where is your `cycle()` function which is called in your code?

Comment: Your JavaScript code contains errors. I'd like to advise you to check the [Console](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201707311435207232224&a=remarks-opening-the-console-0) for errors, try to fix them and [edit] your question.

Comment: `cycle()` is not defined, which throws the error. with that removed your code seems to work. what do you expect? Here's a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ghpm7858/

Answer (score 0):

There you go with a working fiddle:

I just modified CSS a little to make the preview more readable.

**EDIT:**
Your way of using an interval to reset your index is not required for this to work. A better way is to loop through all `div` elements with the class '`.to-charts-screen`'.

On each interval I increment the index (`var i`) by `1` and check if the index has value `3` (this is the **last** div). When this is true we set it back to `0` that the "loop" can start again from the beginning.

And to make things even simpler we just **remove the class on every tick** and just append it to the `div` with the **new index** (`i`).

```js
$(function(){
 var i = 0;
    var elems = $('.to-charts-screen');
 setInterval(function () {
      $(elems).removeClass('over-to-charts-screen');
      $(elems[i]).toggleClass('over-to-charts-screen');
            i = (i == 3) ? 0 : i + 1;        
 }, 1500)
});
```

```css
.over-to-charts-screen {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: background-color .7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="pop-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_1">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_1 over-to-charts-screen" id="screen_1">
      <h5>Pop<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
<a href="rock-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_2">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_2" id="screen_2">
      <h5>Rock<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="country-charts.html">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_3">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_3" id="screen_3">
      <h5>Country<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="latin-charts">
  <div class="to-chart-button" id="music_4">
    <div class="to-charts-screen screen_4" id="screen_4">
      <h5>Latin<br />Charts</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what was wrong with OP's code, what you changed to fix it, etc - your answer is a game of spot-the-difference. Consider adding some more information so that your answer is useful to future readers.

Comment: YES! This seems good. Thank-you so much! Can you describe what this means? i = (i == 3) ? 0 : i + 1;